# Why should we trust someone authenticated via e.g. facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, oauth, single-sign-on

When using OAuth we are using a third party to take care of the authentication of a user.
E.g. when using Facebook we “register” our app with Facebook and when a user of our app tries to login instead of providing to the app his credentials he logs in using his Facebook account.
What I don’t understand is why does the app trust the user? All the app knows is that the user is trusted from Facebook as he has an account there. How can we trust that the user should really access the app?

Comment: Why close? Can I improve the question?

Comment: “Trust them” in regard to _what_, exactly? _“All the app knows is that the user is trusted from Facebook as he has an account there. How can we trust that the user should really access the app?”_ - _you_ decide whether having a Facebook account is enough to access your app.

Comment: Don't you get a unique identifier for this user from Facebook? So that you know it's the same person when she comes back the next day? What more do you need from an authentication service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the "user" you are providing services to is **the Facebook/Google/Instagram/etc. account**. From your perspective, you do not care who the person typing the credentials in is.

Normally, all you know is that the person who logs into your app knows the user name and the password for the account. In the external validation case, you know what the person has this specific login for fb/google/inst and knows the password associated with it.

**Please keep in mind than in most cases (local or external validation), you do not know the person associated with the account** (unless you have some method of personal validation, like credit card or sending a traditional letter with some auth). All you know is that the person who logged in knows the credentials.

Technically, each of those accounts (fb, google, inst) is a separate "user", and your local credentials login is a different one yet.

The whole concept is about user convenience really, plus some additional benefits like having the user data stored and maintained by someone else, additional security and so on.

That said, it is still totally fine if you stick to the "local" credentials method, just make sure it is secure :-)

---

**EDIT:**

A simple example:

Your app has two login options - a simple login with password and login with Google.
You also have a user, John Smith.

John opens your app, which requires login and has some sensitive data connected with each account.

**Scenario 1**. John selects standard, "local" login option and logs in using his credentials JohnSmith1111 and password 12345. John is now able to display the data associated with the account JohnSmith1111.

**Scenario 2**. John selects log in with Google. He is redirected to the login page, authenticates there and returns to your app. Your app is notified that the user google_john_smith has successfully authenticated. John is now able to display the data associated with the account google_john_smith.

The point is that the account validated using those login options is not the same! There is no "trust" issue here.

Comment: So if I have an app that accesses “my servers” and “services” I would normally have a username/password to login in to them if accessed directly e.g. via a browser. But if I delegate the authentication e.g. to FB I still won’t know who the user is right? So maybe this scheme works for specific cases?

Comment: Again, it all comes down to the question if you really need (and can) to know who the user is :-) Just remember that this external auth is NOT an alternative way to log into the same user account. You should treat it as a separate user account :-)

Comment: I am not sure I follow you. Why won’t I need to know who the user is? That’s the whole point of authentication right? What if the servers that he accesses have “sensitive” data?

Comment: I think you have the incorrect idea of trust here. I will add an example